# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '6276.54' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query that keeps throwing the conversion error. I have tried so many ways of making this work but still get the same error. Process of elimination I'm now thinking that this is to do with the hard coded 0.715 value. I'm not sure if or how I force this to be a decimal or if its better to have this SET and a variable at the beginning of my code.

```
SELECT  CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, YEAR) as INT) AS YEAR, 
        COUNT(ID) AS ID,
        SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE,
        SUM(PREMIUM) AS PREMIUM,
        SUM(try_convert(float,USERID1)) AS VALUE1,
        COALESCE(SUM(PREMIUM)/(SUM(try_convert(float,NULLIF(USERID1,0)))*0.715),0) AS 'PROFIT'
        SUM(CAST(USERID1 AS float))/SUM(PREMIUM) AS 'PROFIT%'

INTO #YEAR_VALUE

FROM #DATA LT

INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDB P ON LT.ID = P.ID

GROUP BY INCEPTDATE
```

Any help would be much appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't convert a `varchar` representing a `decimal` to an `int`. Why are you storing numerical values as a `varchar`? To fix the issue, fix the datatype of your column and change it to a `decimal` with the correct scale and precision.  Considering that you have no explicit conversions to an `int` here (apart from `CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, YEAR) as INT)` which isn't applicable here), then you have an implicit conversion; which is unlikely to happen when you correct the data type.

Comment: Hi Larnu, the USERID1 field in the databases we receive is structured as varchar(20). Its a free text column that the client uses for numerical data. Is there a way of handling this as we have no control over it? Thanks

Comment: Try to isolate the problem, keep removing stuff until nothing but the error remains. Then post that query.

Comment: Hi jarlh, I have isolated the issue and it falls over on the following line: COALESCE(SUM(PREMIUM)/(SUM(try_convert(float,NULLIF(USERID1,0)))*0.715),0) AS 'PROFIT'

Comment: *"that the client uses for numerical data."* Then why is it a `varchar` if it *only* contains numerical data?

Comment: Because its a free text column so can contain text as well. Our client uses it for numerical values. Not my choice just what they do NB These are front end users not DBAs so as long as it doesn't error, which it doesn't they will continue to do so. Just makes life harder for people like me.

Comment: Being a front end user has nothing to do with choosing the correct data type in the back end; that's up to the designer (aka you I assume).

Comment: And you are certain that you don't have any non-numerical data in the columns you are trying to convert?

Comment: Larnu, I learnt very early in my career that you should never assume anything before finding out the facts. I'm merely a receiver of the database it's all through a third party platform used by us and the client.

Comment: @Carlos80 to save time and confusion, it's a good idea to add a quick background note on your questions to say things like you have no control of schema etc. People otherwise miss the intent of your perfectly good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some logic back to front, you need to try_parse first, and then do nullif. Try_parse generally returns null if it cannot cast to type specified. You then need to convert null to 0.0

> coalesce(sum(premium)/(sum(nullif(try_convert(float,'userId), 0.0)) * 0.715), 0.0) AS 'profit'

Also, use 0.0 for zero if expecting floats or decimals

Hint: save yours and the next person eyes, no need to use uppercase. That was back in the 70's

Comment: Note that lower vs. upper case is subjective, and it may not be something programmers can control.  I hate having to use upper case for SQL keywords, but company standards require me to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, that worked perfectly! Noted on the uppercase, just something I have become used to because as Paul mentions most of the code written in our company is done in uppercase.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is uppercase considered wrong? and why did it used to be accepted (just to note your 70's reference). Thanks

Comment: @Carlos80 Codd and Date's book on SQL from the 70's had upper case keywords, maybe a limitation of the IBM OS and editors of the time? But time has moved on, we have fancy colour coded editors now, so no need for SHOUTING keyword :-)

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned, It could be possible that you have some non-numerical data within that column. I did the best I could with what I can gather from here to throw together a quick mock up and it seems to work for me with data I have entered. Just testing the line of code you seem to be having issues with.

```
USE DB
GO
CREATE TABLE 
Test_Table (
Premium decimal,
userID varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO 
Test_Table VALUES
(
2.5, 1
)

USE DB
GO
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Premium)/(SUM(try_convert(float,NULLIF(userID,0)))*0.715),0) AS 'PROFIT'
FROM Test_Table;
```

That may point to either some non-numerical data or another line of code being the issue. Just food for though, I know our data and data types probably aren't the exact same.